# broken grid layout and not responsive

Tags: css, grid, css-grid

```css
html {
  font-size: 12px;
}

html,
body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

section {
  border: 2px solid #a77;
  margin: 1em auto;
  max-width: 625px;
  padding: .5em;
  width: 100%;
}

.layout-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 50px);
  grid-gap: 1em;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fix, auto);
}

*,
*::after,
*::before {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.block {
  background-color: #adf;
  border: 1px solid #adf;
  min-height: 100px;
}

.block-item1 {
  grid-row: 1/3;
  grid-column: span 2;
}

.block-item2 {
  grid-row: 1/2;
  grid-column: span 2;
}

.block-item3 {
  grid-row: 2/3;
  grid-column: span 2;
}

.block-item4 {
  grid-row: 1/3;
  grid-column: span 2;
}

.block-item5 {
  grid-row: 1/2;
  grid-column: span 2;
}

.block-item6 {
  grid-row: 2/3;
  grid-column: span 2;
}

.block-item7 {
  grid-row: 1/3;
  grid-column: span 2;
}

.block-item8 {
  grid-column: span 5;
}

.block-item9 {
  grid-column: span 5;
}
```

```html
<section class="layout-grid">
  <div class="block block-item1">1</div>
  <div class="block block-item2">2</div>
  <div class="block block-item3">3</div>
  <div class="block block-item4">4</div>
  <div class="block block-item5">5</div>
  <div class="block block-item6">6</div>
  <div class="block block-item7">7</div>
  <div class="block block-item8">8</div>
  <div class="block block-item9">9</div>
</section>
```

So I have 9 div and I try to make it responsive, but seem like autofill doesn't work. My layout is broken and div is not scale and for example: 1 want 4 div at a medium size and 1 div at the smallest size

If I use a temple map, could I make it responsive? and how to do that is it ok if i use autofill ?

Comment: Thanks for providing your CSS, but can you please provide the relevant HTML as well? It's rather difficult to answer this question without being able to know which elements you're trying to target / exclude. It would help if you could update your question to list **all** relevant code in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If your HTML is generated server-side, could you please post the **output**. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) :)

Comment: Hi
This is my HTML code

<section class="layout-grid">
 <div class="block block-item1">1</div>
 <div class="block block-item2">2</div>
 <div class="block block-item3">3</div>
 <div class="block block-item4">4</div>
 <div class="block block-item5">5</div>
 <div class="block block-item6">6</div>
 <div class="block block-item7">7</div>
 <div class="block block-item8">8</div>
 <div class="block block-item9">9</div>
 
</section>

Comment: Please update your question with the html code